# How to insert form.ui into mainwindow.ui in Qt?

Tags: qt

I placed into the mainwindow QTabWidget with some content. But mainwindow is overloaded, so I decided to put the logic of the elements in each tab into a separate class, i.e. 6 more files appears in my project:

```
MyTabWidget1.h
MyTabWidget1.cpp
MyTabWidget1.ui

MyTabWidget2.h
MyTabWidget2.cpp
MyTabWidget2.ui
```

Now I want the contents of the tabs to appear in the main window's Tab Widget. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options to compose widgets:

1) In Designer mode of Creator using the promote widget functionality. Add the pages into the tab-widget in designer, make sure you select each page individually not the QTabWidget (you can do that in the object browser, each page will be a child of the QTabWidget) select `Promote to...` in the context menu for each individual page and enter the corresponding class name and header filenames in the dialog that opens.

2) using C++ code you can access the tab widget inside main window class and use [addTab](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#addTab)

```
//in the constructor of mainwindow you can do something like this:
ui->TABWIDGET->addTab(new MyTabWidget1(), "First tab");
ui->TABWIDGET->addTab(new MyTabWidget2(), "Second tab");
//replace TABWIDGET with the corresponding name you used for your tab widget in the mainwindow.ui
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I need.